# Basic flask implementation of Docsify documentation

Tags: python, flask, docsify

I came across Docsify (https://docsify.js.org/#/) and have had fun experimenting with it. I'm interested in serving some documentation using my own flask server, instead of Github Pages or with node, however I can't figure out how to implement it.

As described by Docsify (https://docsify.js.org/#/quickstart?id=manual-initialization), locally serving a simple`index.html` to render and `README.md` as the markdown content works beautifully.

`index.html`

```
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/docsify/themes/vue.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script>
    window.$docsify = {
      //...
    }
  </script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/docsify/lib/docsify.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`README.md`

```
# Hi, I'm markdown content
```

Command line to run the static server (works):

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3000
```

Now, in Flask, I am using the app factory + blueprints pattern, and as far as flask is concerned everything works as expected. I can add a new endpoint and it renders just fine. My file structure:

```
├── instance
│   └── flask.cfg
├── main.py
├── project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── front
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── routes.py
│   │   └── templates
│   │       └── front
│   │           └── index.html
│   ├── documentation
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── routes.py
│   │   └── templates
│   │       └── documentation
│   │           ├── README.md
│   │           └── index.html
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   └── style.css
│   └── templates
│       └── base.html
└── requirements.txt
```

In the `project -> documentation -> documentation` folder I am adding a `README.md` at the same level as I did with the above Docsify example that gets served locally so well.

The `index.html` loads via flask (look carefully and you'll see a sidebar and hamburger menu button), but the markdown content does not and I get '404 - Not found' message.
[image: docsify 404]

I simply don't know how to implement this, let alone how to do it elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

here is what i do:

```
location /doc/ {
    index index.html;
    root /www/api/templates;
}
```

and then u can access your documention at /doc like mine:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebcd3.png)

and here is my outlook of my site(written by pure html):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkn0s.png)

Comment: this requires him to use nginx

Comment: @alessandrocaprarelli yes, it is

Answer (score 0):

If you serve your `index.html` at the root of your site (i.e local dev at 3000: `localhost:3000/`), docsify will try to get all the other files starting from the same level. In your case it expects to find the `README.md` at this endpoint `localhost:3000/README.md`.

You could do as follows:

- create a route in your flask server like `/documentation` that serves all the files inside the documentation folder. In this way you will get the `README.md` file at `/documentation/README.md`
- add in the docsify config the `basePath` property (https://docsify.js.org/#/configuration?id=basepath): `basePath: '/documentation/'`

In this way you should be able to access all your `.md` files from the route `/documentation/*` and docsify will successfully renders them.